# Check column datatype and execute SQL only on Integer and Decimal in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to check datatype of a column from the input Parquet file, if the datatype is Integer or Decimal then run Spark SQL.

```
//get Array of structfields 
 val datatypes = parquetRDD_subset.schema.fields

//Check datatype of column
 for (val_datatype <- datatypes)  if (val_datatype.dataType.typeName == "integer" || val_datatype.dataType.typeName.contains("decimal"))  
{
 //get the field name
val x = parquetRDD_subset.schema.fieldNames

 val dfs = x.map(field => spark.sql(s"select 'DataProfilerStats' as Table_Name,(SELECT 100 * approx_count_distinct($field)/count(1) from parquetDFTable) as Percentage_Unique_Value from parquetDFTable"))

 }
```

The issue is, although, datatype validation is successful, while inside the for loop after getting field names, it is not actually restricting the columns just to integer or decimals, the query is being performed on all the columns types even strings as well. How do we get the fields which only are Decimal or Integer. How do we address this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can filter the columns with integer and double type

```
// fiter the columns 
val columns = df.schema.fields.filter(x => x.dataType == IntegerType || x.dataType == DoubleType)

//use these filtered with select 
df.select(columns.map(x => col(x.name)): _*)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Shankar ! The provided solution does actually filters Integer and Decimal but how do we pass this to my existing sql which is - val dfs = x.map(field => spark.sql(s"select 'DataProfilerStats' as Table_Name,(SELECT 100 * approx_count_distinct($field)/count(1) from parquetDFTable) as Percentage_Unique_Value from parquetDFTable")). Here $field is column name from the input dataframe. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Thanks Shankar again ! I figured out the easiest part :) ..val m = z.columns, m being the above last step mentioned in your code, followed by val dfs = m.map(field => spark.sql(s"select ...) ..it is operating on the restricted columns..you are awesome as usual !!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val names = df.schema.fields.collect { 
  case StructField(name, DecimalType(), _, _) => approx_count_distinct(name)
  case StructField(name, IntegerType, _, _)   => approx_count_distinct(name)
}

spark.table("parquetDFTable").select(names: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks random-impressions for your answer ! but approx_count_distinct is making this operation a bit slow given that the data size is going to be in millions. How do we add the below statement along with the code which you have provided... val dfs = names.map(field => spark.sql(s"select 'DataProfilerStats' as Table_Name, '$field' as Column_Name from parquetDFTable"))

      val withSum = dfs.reduce((x, y) => x.union(y)).distinct().coalesce(1)
      withSum.show()